# Non-nullable instance field 'painter' must be initialized in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

[image: Photo of the code]I am trying to figure out what is causing this error in the code. It seems like the painter side is causing issues. Been trying to figure this out for some time. I'd love any hints or tips on this. This seems like a change with Flutter 3.0 that took place I suppose.

```
BubbleIndicatorPainter({this.dxTarget = 125.0, this.dxEntry = 25.0, this.radius = 21.0,
this.dy = 25.0, required this.pageController}) : super(repaint: pageController) {
painter = Paint()
    ..color = CustomTheme.white
    ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;


}




Paint painter;
  final double dxTarget;
  final double dxEntry;
  final double radius;
  final double dy;
```

Comment: Use late Paint painter

Answer (score 1):

You can use `late` that you will assign data before reading it

```
late Paint painter;
```

Or you can make it nullable

```
 Paint? painter;
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
late Paint painter;  Here late assures you will initiate the painter later in the program.
```

Or

```
Paint? painter;   Here you are saying painter can be null to the dart compiler
```

This is error caused because of the dart null safety